# Deployment getting timeout on blackberry10 device

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to run cordova blackberry application in my blackberry 10 device. I am getting following error.

```
$ platforms/blackberry10/cordova $ ./build

[INFO]    Populating application source 
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml 
[INFO]    Generating output files 
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/pavunkumar/BlackBerry/bb10/platforms/blackberry10/build/simulator/bb10app.bar
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/pavunkumar/BlackBerry/bb10/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/bb10app.bar 
[INFO]    BAR packaging complete

$ ./target add pavunkumar 169.254.0.1 -t device --password 0613  --pin 335921E0
$ ./run  blackberry10 --target=pavunkumar --devicepass 0613 

 [INFO]    Target pavunkumar selected 
 [INFO]    The existing debug  token is valid 
 [INFO]    Deploying debug token to target "pavunkumar"
 [INFO]    Error: Cannot connect: Connect to /169.254.0.1:443 timed
 out. Please check IP address settings for the target. You may have to
 reboot the target. An error has occurred
```

I have enabled the development mode in my phone. 
But I am able to ping the mentioned IP and am able to make telnet towards  169.254.0.1 443 .

What can be the reason ?

**Note**

I am able to install the sample Native application in my z10 using Momentics IDE

Comment: In addition to that, please confirm the following
- Are you using Webworks 2. or CLI
- Are you trying to install via USB or via Wifi

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your problem without all the details, but from my experience the greatest problems with cordova communications relate to cross origin resource sharing (CORS).
In your config.xml you need to have something like:

```
  <access subdomains="true" uri="169.254.0.1"/>
```

On the server side you need to also enable CORS, so the headers should include:

```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin ...."
```